# About extensions of finitely generated modules.

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity, and $A \subseteq B$ be $R$-modules.

I want to know if the following is true:

> If $A, B/A$ are finitely generated $R$-modules, then $B$ is finitely generated.

Under some stronger hypothesis, this is true. For example:

1. if $R$ is Noetherian, then finitely generated is equivalent to Noetherian. Since $$0 \to A \to B \to B/A \to 0$$ is exact, and $A, B/A$ are Noetherian, then $B$ is Noetherian as well.
2. if $B/A$ is finite, then write $B= \bigcup_{k=1}^n x_k+A$, where this is a finite disjoint union. If $a_1, \dots, a_m$ generate $A$, then $B$ is generated by the $a_i, x_k$ so it is finitely generated.

Can you provide me a proof for the general case, or a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_1+A,b_2+A,\dots,b_m+A$ be generators of $B/A$ and let $a_1,\dots,a_n$ be generators of $A$.

If $b\in B$, then
$$
b+A=\sum_{i=1}^m r_i(b_i+A)=\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^m r_ib_i\biggr)+A
$$
for some $r_1,\dots,r_m\in R$, which means
$$
b-\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^m r_ib_i\biggr)=\sum_{j=1}^n s_ja_j
$$
for some $s_1,\dots,s_n\in R$, so
$$
b=\sum_{i=1}^m r_ib_i+\sum_{j=1}^n s_ja_j
$$

Comment: Oh, this was so easy. This is (almost) the same argument I used in my point 2. Isn't it?

Comment: @Crostul Yes, that was it.